# Table 'db_session' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: sql, mariadb, innodb

trying to run this sql query but i'm getting the error above:

```
DELETE FROM db_session
where time NOT IN (SELECT MAX(time) FROM db_session GROUP BY username)
```

`SELECT` function though works as expected.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only database that causes this problem (as far as I know) is MySQL (and related databases). You can replace the logic with a `JOIN`:

```
delete s
    from db_session s join
         (select username, max(time) as maxtime
          from db_session s2
          group by username
         ) ss
         on s.username = ss.username and s.time < ss.maxtime;
```

An added bonus is that the logic is also correct.  Your logic deletes any rows where the time is not the maximum time for *any* `username`.  However, if it could keep multiple rows for a user name if the different rows happen to be the maximum time for some *other* user.

Comment: this returns and deletes all the rows on the table, i wanna have all the unique "username" rows with the max "time" each has. for example if there's three "user1" and two "user2" rows i wanna keep the one with the max time for "user1" and the one with the max time for "user2".

Comment: @NickKapenkar . . . This should not be deleting all the rows in the table.  The `s.time < ss.maxtime)` is doing exactly the logic you want.

Comment: there's 39 rows total in the table, the query deletes them all!

Comment: @NickKapenkar . . . It is fixed.  (Why did I put in a `left join` to begin with?)

Comment: i think it's working as expected, thank you very much